# how to create new section in checkout page - woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

in checkout page of woocommerce, 
i want to create new (block or section), i don't know how to call to OK.

such as live demo :
http://tigon.freshbrand.vn/checkout/

or img description my problems : http://prntscr.com/eum61d

i want to create more section like this.

```
MY SECTION FORM 1 TITLE.
 - input 1
 - input 2

MY SECTION FORM 2 TITLE
 - input 3
 - input 4

MY SECTION FORM 3 TITLE
 - input 5
 - input 6
```

how to solve this,
help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code to add section in checkout page. I have added only content in the section for you. You can add fields also.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_before_customer_details','checkout_sections');
function checkout_sections(){
    echo '<div>';
        echo '<h3 id="order_review_heading">'. __( 'New Section', 'woocommerce' ).'</h3>';
        echo '<div>';
        echo 'My contents';
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Use JS to make your sections toggle.

Comment: oh yeah, it' work....
but i want this form below billing form.
what action i can use to do that ?

Comment: There is no such action between billing and shipping fields. But after shipping there is a hook `woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details`